# How can I validate a SOAP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax, soap

Is there a a quick way to validate SOAP messages? I have seen validator for JSON objects. Is there something like this for SOAP? I am receiving a 'Bad Request: 400' error response with a AJAX post I am working on. I am not too familiar with SOAP as I typically just pass JSON. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my request or perhaps suggest a good way to debug it myself? Firebug error message is just  'Bad Request: 400' which doesn't really help.

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap:Body>
        <UpdateAutoChart xmlns='http://somewhere.org/hwconnect/services' soap:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding'>alertid=Test&companytoken=hw&autochart=false</UpdateAutoChart>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my POST function:

```js
function doPost(method, body) {
    var soapRequest = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' ";
    soapRequest = soapRequest + "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>";
    soapRequest = soapRequest + "<soap:Body>"
    soapRequest = soapRequest + "<" + method + " xmlns='http://somewhere.org/hwconnect/services' soap:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding'>"; 
    soapRequest = soapRequest + body;
    soapRequest = soapRequest + "</" + method + ">";
    soapRequest = soapRequest + "</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\";");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://somewhere.org/hwconnect/services/" + method);
        },
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: theURL,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\";",
        data: soapRequest,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("XMLHttpRequest Failure: " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also, look at the wire and post the complete XML that is actually sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a SOAP issue but an issue with how you're posting the data:

[400 error explained](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html)

I'd examine the final HTTP headers you're sending to verify they are correct (especially the data size)

Comment: Going to take a look at the headers.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know json but soapaction header should look like this

```
SOAPAction: "myaction"
```

so the line:

```
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://somewhere.org/hwconnect/services/" + method);
```

should probably look like this to be correct:

```
xhrObj.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "\"http://somewhere.org/hwconnect/services/" + method + "\"");
```